# Playing long sound in local notification iOS10

Tags: ios, ios10, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have a custom sound playing on local notification, in iOS 10 when the device is locked everything works fine and the sound plays till the end. But when the device is unlocked, as soon as the notification bar hides ( in about 5 Secs.) the sound stops playing.

PS. It works fine in iOS 9, the notification bar stays on top as long as the notification sound is playing.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I've tested with either `UNUserNotificationCenter` and deprecated `UILocalNotification`. Both the same result.

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any answer to it ?

Comment: I filed for a bug in developer.apple.com and they've responded that this bug is duplicate of another bug report with number xxxx. So it's a bug! I hope they fix it ASAP!

Comment: Hope they do. Write now, I changed the notification alert style to "alerts" from "banners" and then it seem to work. But the problem again is, we cannot do that programatically.